# ffmpeg executed from Java's processbuilder does not return under windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, process, return

I was trying to build up a ProcessBuilder calling the ffmpeg binary.
My problem is that calling it, it returns perfectly under MacOs, Ubuntu and WindowsXp,
but under Windows7 the waitFor() never returns.

Has anyone similar experience under windows 7? Any help would be appreciated!

My command:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( );

pb.command( "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c", "c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", "-version" );
```

Tried these ones too:

```
pb.command( "c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", "-version" ); 
pb.command( "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c", "start c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -version" );
```

Result is the same. :(

Comment: FYI, ffmpeg's stdout stream writes to the stderr channel. Not sure if this is a bug, or if ffmpeg won't fix it for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your process writes something in its out and/or err streams. Their buffer overflow and process blocks. You should read out and err streams of your process to avoid this.

See  "[When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)"  for more information

Comment: +1  The 'single line call' to get a `Process` rarely works.  One should not wonder why it breaks until having implemented *all* the suggestions in [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java 7 you could do something like that :

```
File encodingFile = new File(outfile + ".encoding");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(vars.config.ffmpeg, "-i", file, "-y", "-s", width + "x" + height, "-vcodec", "libvpx", outfile); //or other command....
encodingFile.createNewFile();
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE); //optional, default behavior
pb.redirectOutput(encodingFile);
Process p = pb.start();

// if you want to wait for the process to finish
p.waitFor();
encodingFile.delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

you should do something like this

```
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( );
        pb.command( "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c", 
        "c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", "-version" ); 
        Process process = pb.start();
        OutputStream stdOutput = process.getOutputStream();
        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
```

then it will work as your process is giving some output but you are not reading it